# how do I rename tooltip of echart download icon

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I am using  [echarts](http://echarts.baidu.com/index.html)

How do I rename download button tooltip in corner of top-right(written in Chinese language)

I can't find in echart option.

<kbd>[image: Picture of my chart]</kbd>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `title` to rename the tooltip, for example:

```
toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
        downloadTable: {
            show: true,
            // Show the title when mouse focus
            title: 'Save As picture',
            // Icon path
            icon: '/static/img/download-icon.png',  
            option: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to add logo to downloaded image?

Comment: For anyone looking for other options, here's the official doc: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions, it has changed to :

```
toolbox: {
    feature: {
        saveAsImage: {
           // Show the title when mouse focus
            title: 'Save As picture'
        }
    }
}
```